# Post apocalyptic movie where men and women have split into separate tribes as they each believe the other side are infectious

Tags: story-identification, movie

I caught part of this movie on TV years ago and I've never seen it since, or been able to find out what it was called. It looked like it was made during the 70's, but I can't be sure of that.

Most of humanity has been wiped out by a contagion. It is suggested (but not confirmed) that it may have been a bio weapon. Men and women have split into separate tribes, and will kill each other on sight, as well as any of their own who come into contact with a member of the opposite sex, as they each believe that the other side are carrying the disease.

In actual fact, everyone is already infected, and the virus is activated during sex, horribly killing both participants shortly afterwards.

I remember two scenes specifically. In the first, a man attacks a woman he finds on her own, but is discovered by his own people, who kill him. The woman escapes and makes it back to her tribe, where they kill her rather than let the disease run its course.

In the second, there is a small farming community that contains both men and women, who, we are told, are aware that they can live together safely as long as they are celibate. They are attacked  by the male tribe seeking supplies. When some of them react with surprise after the raid that there are both men and women among the dead, their leader refuses to acknowledge this, saying something like "I can't see any men".

Comment: Sounds like fifth grade, and the 'cooties' ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### [*Terminal Virus*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113607/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt) (1995)

It was a made for TV movie as part of the [*Roger Corman Presents*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Corman_Presents) series for the Showtime TV network by Roger Corman.

> It has been 23 years since a world war during which combatants unleashed a lab-created virus that has made life no fun at all. Civilization has broken down into forcibly celibate, warring male and female tribes. Any co mingling, even rape, is punished by both sides with summary execution, for victim and perpetrator alike. A paramilitary fanatic on a vague religious mission leads his gunmen to massacre a peaceful scientific community where men and women committed the blasphemy of co-ed habitation.

> In a barren future, a mysterious virus has made sex and childbirth fatal, and men and women have separated into armed camps at war. The last survivor of a colony, which has perfected a cure, tries to cut through the hatred and paranoia in order to restart humanity.

Just picking a random image from IMDb it does look like a 70's movie per your recollection:

[image: Two women from the film]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

<sub>*Found with the Google query `"movie" "apocalypse" "virus" activated by "sex" die afterwards site:imdb.com/title`.*</sub>